# Pull current date in power query

Tags: datetime, excel-formula, powerquery

Want to write a query like "select * from table where date = "04/08/2022" for an excel that connects to my SQL server.

My current power query formula works: = Table.SelectRows(dbo_Main, each [Date] = #datetime(2022, 4, 08, 0, 0, 0)) but I do not want to have to update the date manually every day.

To try to automate it I used Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) which should work as it returns ("04/08/2022") but the query does not end up pulling any of the data.

Pretty confused, and do not have much experience in power query to know where to go from here

*advanced editor code

```
Source = Sql.Databases("server name"),
#"Database Name" = Source{[Name="Database Name"]}[Data],
dbo_Main = #"Database Name"{[Schema="dbo",Item="Main"]}[Data],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_Main, each [Date] = 
Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0GVP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it should work

```
= Table.SelectRows(dbo_Main, each [Date] = Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))
```

is the code I am using to change the top to bottom image

[image]

If that doesnt work for you, edit your question to paste in the code you are using from home ... advanced editor...

Comment: Not sure why it is not working either. Maybe my sql formatting is throwing it off?
This is straight from my table:
2022-04-08 00:00:00.000

Yet when I try your formula I get no entries

Comment: post a screenshot of the corner of your file like I did above.  Is the column formatted as a date or text? Is the cell contents text or a date?  What happens if you transform the data type of the Date column to Date before filtering?

Comment: could not post the image directly due to some restriction, but there should be a link to the image in the original post

Comment: thats what it looks like in Excel not what it looks like in powerquery